# Trouble understanding LatLngBounds using GoogleMaps in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I have the coordinates of my current location and I am trying to find out how to get the NE and SW corners from my current location on Google Maps using LatLngBounds.

I don't seem to understand how to implement LatLngBounds from the API Google has written here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/mobile/android/reference/com/google/android/m4b/maps/model/LatLngBounds

If someone could explain to me what LatLngBounds actually does and how to use it that would be great. Please let me know if I need to add more information to clear anything up.

Thank you.

Comment: "I am trying to find out how to get the NE and SW corners from my current location" -- an individual location does not have corners. `LatLngBounds` is for finding the bounding rectangle around a collection of locations, not just one.

Answer (score 0):

A LatLng is a point; a LatLngBounds is a rectangle.  So at a minimum, to construct a LatLngBounds, you need TWO LatLngs:  one for the SouthWest corner of the rectangle, and one for the NorthEast corner of the rectangle.  Given those two points, the other two points of the rectangle are trivially computed.

Its not clear from your question WHY you need a LatLngBounds.  You should only need that if you plan to put some imagery onto the map, or draw some type of rectangle.  If you just want to show a marker or an infobox you don't need a LatLngBounds.

If you plan to use say GroundOverlay to show an image centered upon a LatLng point, its more complicated than you think.  You will have to use a geolocation mapping tool that lets you place the image onto the map, resize it to fit how you like, then that tool will give you the NE and SW LatLngs you need for the LatLngBounds for the GroundOverlay.

Answer (score 0):

`LatLngBounds` is a rectangle which is described by two `LatLng` objects for North-East and South-West as you know.

You can easily construct a LatLng from your current location with getting `Projection` of the map camera.

1. (Optional) Move the camera to the center of your screen, i.e have your current location at the center.
2. Use `getVisibleRegion()` method to get the current visible rectangle.
3. From `VisibleRegion` object extract `farLeft` and `farRight` `LatLng` properties or just `LatLngBounds` property
4. These coordinates will give you the `LatLngBounds` of the current location

Alternatively, you can use `LatLngBounds.Builder` and construct NE and SW coordiantes by converting Points on the screen to LatLng, using [fromScreenCoordinates()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/Projection.html#fromScreenLocation(android.graphics.Point)) method which takes `Point` as argument.

Norteast `Point` should be at `x=0, y=mapView.getRight();`

Southwest `Point` should be at `x=0, y=mapView.getBottom();`

(Correct me, if I'm wrong)